# Your Sitemap does not contain any URLs. Please validate and resubmit your Sitemap

Tags: wordpress, seo

Why this sitemaps in google webmaster tools show this error "Your Sitemap does not contain any URLs. Please validate and resubmit your Sitemap."

Sitemaps: `http://www.ciadeeventosbuffet.com.br/sitemap_index.xml`
Plugin: Yoast Seo Plugin

Comment: I have the same issue,did you find any solution?

Comment: I also have same, any luck ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 7):

### Cause:

The problem, in my case, was caused by a plugin conflict with "All In One WP Security".

### Solution:

From the WordPress menu on the left navigate to WP Security >> Firewall and look for the "Internet Bots" tab. Deactivate the "Block Fake Googlebots" option and click save.

This solution solved my problem for sitemaps generated by both the "Yoast SEO" plugin for WordPress and the "Google XML Sitemaps" plugin for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe because your sitemap contains with other sitemaps URL and there is no URL of your website. Try to add these sitemaps which are listed on `http://www.ciadeeventosbuffet.com.br/sitemap_index.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and the solution to deactivate Fake Google Bots in the WP Security plugin was the solution that worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34425623)